# Options "put to you"

Tags: options

What does it mean when you have an option you bought "put to you" after the last trading day?

Answer (score 3):

If you bought a put option you would be selling shares to someone else.  If you sell a put option you sold someone else the option to force you to take shares at a given price.

Comment: Might want to add for clarity that if you are the buyer, stock cannot be put to you. Only put to the seller.

Comment: That's not correct Joe.  U.S. options that expire $0.01 ITM are automatically exercised by the OCC (Exercise By Exception) unless designated by the owner to the broker that they not be exercised.

Answer (score 1):

The seller of a put receives a premium from the buyer of the put. The seller has the obligation to buy 100 shares at the strike price. If the  put buyer exercises the put contract, the seller must buy 100 shares (standard contract) at the strike price no matter what  the current value of the stock is.

"Put To You" is slang for having your put assigned (the buyer exercises it) and having to buy the shares.  IOW, the shares are "Put To You".

A variation of this would be owning a long call that is in-the-money  at expiration.  The OCC (U.S.) automatically exercises options that expire $0.01 ITM if you failed to designate to your broker that the contract not be exercised.  If auto exercised, your long call would also result in your having to buy shares, aka having the shares put to you via a different market mechanism.